# d3js charts and graphs: a multichoice list

Tags: d3.js

Is it possible to create a choice list of different d3js graphs types and once the user pick a choice the graph appears in the all the space of the page and when he pick another type the area will be devided into two spaces showing two graphs of the same data and etc...

Comment: Sure, make your menu and then apply the requested d3 chart when the users select a menu item. Build a fiddle and let us know if you have problems

Answer (score 0):

For the d3js part of your question it is maybe important to mention that in D3 a datum can be bound to different DOM elements without direct dependency between these DOM elements. In the following example we have one dataset for which each of the six values is bound to both a blue and a red circle.

http://jsfiddle.net/DorjeDuck/sxfdq/3/

one data set, two groups ...

```
var radius = 21,
w = 400,
h = 200;

var body = d3.select("body");
body.append("button")
.text("go")
.on("click", function () {
    newCircles.start();
})

body.append("br");
body.append("br");

var svg = body
.append("svg")
.attr("class", "svg")
.attr("width", w)
.attr("height", h)
.append("g")
.attr("transform", "translate(" + radius + "," + radius + ")");

var newCircles = function () {

var data = [];
var counter = 0;
var interval;

var nc = function () {

    data.push(counter);

    svg.selectAll(".group1")
        .data(data)
        .enter()
        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "group1")
        .attr("cx", 30)
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
            return d * 30;
        })
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("fill", "blue");

    svg.selectAll(".group2")
        .data(data)
        .enter()

        .append("circle")
        .attr("class", "group2")
        .attr("cx", 30)
        .attr("cy", function (d) {
            return d * 30;
        })
        .attr("r", 10)
        .attr("fill", "red")
        .transition()
        .delay(100)
        .duration(300)
        .attr("cx", 100)


    if (++counter > 5) {
        clearInterval(interval);

        svg.selectAll(".group1")
            .data(data)
            .transition()
            .delay(200)
            .duration(1000)
            .attr("cx", "300");
    }
}

nc.start = function () {
    svg.selectAll("circle").remove();
    data = [];
    counter = 0;
    clearInterval(interval);
    interval = setInterval(newCircles, 500);
}

return nc;
}();
```